# SQL - Subquery more than one value

Tags: sql, subquery

I am getting the following error when trying to use subqueries.

> Subquery returned more than 1 value. `This is not permitted when the subquery follows =, !=, <, <= , >, >= or when the subquery is used as an expression.`

In the full code I will be doing more subqueries and changing the `datediff(day, open_dt, trn.tran_dt) = '0' to 30, 60 and 90`.

I'm happy or not use subqueries if there is an easier way.

```
SELECT 
    chn.acct_identifier,
    acq_channel, 
    COUNT(ExpRowId) [total transactions],
    (SELECT COUNT(trn.ExpRowId) 
     FROM hrg_prod.client.acquisition_table chn
     LEFT JOIN hrg_prod.prd.[transaction] trn ON CHN.acct_identifier = trn.applid 
                                              AND trn.trans_cd = 101 
                                              AND trn.auth_cd IS NOT NULL 
                                              AND trn.merch_num IS NOT NULL
     WHERE open_dt > '01Jul17'
       AND DATEDIFF(DAY, open_dt, trn.tran_dt) = '0' 
     GROUP BY 
         acct_identifier, Acq_Channel, chn.open_dt) [0 days],
    (select sum(trn.amt_tran) FROM hrg_prod.client.acquisition_table chn
left JOIN hrg_prod.prd.[transaction] trn
                 ON CHN.acct_identifier = trn.applid 
                   AND trn.trans_cd = 101 
                   AND trn.auth_cd IS NOT NULL 
                   AND trn.merch_num IS NOT NULL
where open_dt > '01Jul17'
and datediff(day, open_dt, trn.tran_dt) = '0' 
group by acct_identifier, Acq_Channel, chn.open_dt) [0 days tran],

chn.open_dt,
min(tran_dt) [first trans_dt],
datediff(day, open_dt, min(tran_dt)) [date difference]
FROM hrg_prod.client.acquisition_table chn
left JOIN hrg_prod.prd.[transaction] AS trn 
                ON CHN.acct_identifier = trn.applid 
                   AND trn.trans_cd = 101 
                   AND trn.auth_cd IS NOT NULL 
                   AND trn.merch_num IS NOT NULL
 where open_dt > '01Jul17'
 group by acct_identifier, Acq_Channel, chn.open_dt
```

If I use just one acct_identifier like so I get the following results

```
SELECT chn.acct_identifier,
acq_channel,
count(ExpRowId) [total transactions],
chn.open_dt,
min(tran_dt) [first trans_dt],
FROM   hrg_prod.client.acquisition_table chn
   left JOIN hrg_prod.prd.[transaction] AS trn 
                ON CHN.acct_identifier = trn.applid 
                   AND trn.trans_cd = 101 
                   AND trn.auth_cd IS NOT NULL 
                   AND trn.merch_num IS NOT NULL
where chn.acct_identifier = '6675378'
group by acct_identifier, Acq_Channel, chn.open_dt

acct_identifier | acq_channes | transactions | open_dt    | first tran_dt 
6675378         | Online      | 16           | 2017-08-04 | 2017-08-04
```

What I want to do is have more transaction columns where I put filters on datediff(day, open_dt, trn.tran_dt) <= '?'

Comment: Tell us what you want to achieve. Best with sample records and desired output. So far, you are selecting rows with the record's value of `chn.acct_identifier` and its value of `acq_channel`, but also `(select ... group by)`. This subquery returns several rows because of `group by` when it should only be one of course.

Comment: The error message says it all. Either you want only one row from it, then decide which row - and select only that row. Or skip the sub-qeury, to a left join instead.

Comment: You are getting what you coded to get. It's not really clear what you are asking for.

Comment: By the way, this won't work: `open_dt > '01Jul17'`. You are looking for strings greater than `'01Jul17'`. This is true for `'02Jan13'`, because '2' > '1' and false for `'01Aug19'`, for 'A' < ' J'.

Comment: I have added to the question, I hope this helps. What I want is more transaction columns but the new columns are filtered on the date difference between open_dt and tran_dt

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm pretty sure you don't need subqueries, just conditional aggregation.  Your question is a bit hard to follow, but I think this is what you want:

```
select chn.acct_identifier, acq_channel, 
       count(ExpRowId) as [total transactions],
       sum(case when datediff(day, open_dt, trn.tran_dt) = 0 and
                       trn.applid is not null
                  then 1 else 0
             end) as [0 days],
       sum(case when datediff(day, open_dt, trn.tran_dt) = 0 and
                       trn.applid is not null
                  then trn.amt_tran else 0
             end) as [0 days],
            chn.open_dt,
            min(tran_dt) [first trans_dt],
            datediff(day, open_dt, min(tran_dt)) as [date difference]
from hrg_prod.client.acquisition_table chn left join
     hrg_prod.prd.[transaction] AS trn 
     on CHN.acct_identifier = trn.applid and
        trn.trans_cd = 101 and
        trn.auth_cd IS NOT NULL and
        trn.merch_num IS NOT NULL
where open_dt > '01Jul17'
group by acct_identifier, Acq_Channel, chn.open_dt;
```